# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'%' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know why I get this error when running `mysqlimport`?

```
mysqlimport: Error: 1045, Access denied for user 'user'@'%' (using password: YES), when using table: XXX
```

I have tried so many options. Also I am not able to run the below command as referred by some sites:

```
mysql> GRANT FILE ON *.* to 'user'@'%';

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Answer (score 1):

try this 
step 1

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

step 2

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

if you want to add password

step 1

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

step 2

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

for more details [ref](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-mysql-user-accounts-and-grant-privileges/)
in hear I add `ALL PRIVILEGES` for `all databases` if you want to change it refer I added [link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-mysql-user-accounts-and-grant-privileges/)
without executing `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` you can restart SQL server I think to execute `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` is better